# Is there any way to install CPanel/WHM in ubuntu 13.04 server?

Tags: 13.04

I recently install ubuntu server 13.04 on vmware. Now I want to know that is there any way to install cpanel/whm on this server?

Regards,
 Mahbub

Answer (score 2):

According to [cPanel](http://cpanel.net/cpanel-whm/system-requirements/), cPanel/WHM does not support Ubuntu or any Ubuntu derivative.

Current discussions about re-introducing Debian support and adding support for Ubuntu Server LTS can be found on the [Feature Request Forum](http://forums.cpanel.net/f145/debian-support-ubuntu-server-lts-support-153517.html).